# Comparison Graph

Tags: graphics

I want to draw the combine comparison graph of the following four sequences (note that two are approximatly equal), each one have different colors and lables etc

AK

```
  g[x_] := (((3/4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + (1/
               4)*(((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 
            2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3);
    NumberForm[NestList[g, 1.99, 11], 16]
```

Picard-S:=

```
g[x_] := ((3/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + (1/
        4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3);
NumberForm[NestList[g, 1.99, 11], 16]
```

Vatan Two-step

```
g[x_] := ((3/4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + (1/
        4)*(((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 
     2)^(1/3);
NumberForm[NestList[g, 1.99, 11], 16]
```

Thakur-New

```
g[x_] := ((((3/4)*x + (1/4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3))) + 2)^(1/
        3) + 2)^(1/3);
NumberForm[NestList[g, 1.99, 11], 16]
```

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What kind of graph? Do you just mean four listplots in one?

Comment: @Feyre Yes, But I want clear picture and different colors so that it can clearly visible, Please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ak[x_] := (((3/4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + (1/
           4)*(((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 
        2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3);
picardS[x_] := ((3/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + (1/
        4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3);
vatan[x_] := ((3/4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + (1/
        4)*(((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3) + 
     2)^(1/3);
thakur[x_] := ((((3/4)*x + (1/4)*((3/4)*x + (1/4)*(x + 2)^(1/3))) + 
        2)^(1/3) + 2)^(1/3);
ListPlot[
  Log10@
   {
     NestList[ak, 1.99`20, 11] - Nest[ak, 1.99`20, 11],
     NestList[picardS, 1.99`20, 11] - Nest[picardS, 1.99`20, 11],
     NestList[vatan, 1.99`20, 11] - Nest[vatan, 1.99`20, 11],
     NestList[thakur, 1.99`20, 11] - Nest[thakur, 1.99`20, 11]
   },
  PlotRange -> All,
  PlotLegends -> {"AK", "Picard-S", "Vatan Two-Step", "Thakur-New"}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks @MarcoB but the picture is not clear.... What can we do so to get clear picture

Comment: @Marwat I don't see how you can get a clearer picture when the difference between the lists is much smaller than the value differences per x-value

Comment: @Marwat Take a look at the new version, a logarithmic plot of the difference between the current value and the convergence value for each sequence.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MarcoB I think now it is a clear image.